Font-maker for maplibre
How can I install
https://github.com/maplibre/font-maker/tree/main
in Debian 12 so that I can use it via command line?
There is a link to https://github.com/protomaps/basemaps-assets , but I cannot see how I can do it.
What I did:
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
sudo apt install clang
~/font-maker$ cmake .

But font-maker is not found on the system.

run make after cmake . perhaps - https://github.com/maplibre/font-maker/blob/main/CONTRIBUTING.md#building-command-line
